# Multiple android:inputTypes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In the xml, can you do multiple `android:inputType=""`?

I type two statements on different lines, but the compiler gave me an error.
Are there any other ways to declare multiple `inputTypes` for a single `editText`, preferably in the xml?

Answer (score 2):

Just seperate the options with a '|'. It can look like this:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the xml:

```
android:inputType="textClassText|textNoSuggestions"
```

Or programmatically as:

```
your_editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```